# Jenkins CPU load >100%

Tags: jenkins, linux-kernel, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins seem to initiate a kernel process which consume CPU to max as seen in the snapshot.
[image]

Stopping Jenkins doesn't seem to help either. It stays the same even if I stop Jenkins. Apparently this can happen when a high speed network card receives a very large number of packets in a short time frame. But I'm absolutely clueless on how to go about it or to fix it. Any help/input would be greatly appreciated.

**System Specifications:** 
    This is an EC2 instance
    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
    CORES=8
    MEM=16GB

Comment: System Specifications ?
And where it is hosted ?

Comment: @MajidRehman I've added it in the question

Comment: is it open to the world ?

Comment: If yess than please restrict access only to your IP

Comment: @MajidRehman your comments makes sense. I cleaned up my security group inbound rules which fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: Wellcome @Red Bottle